# Why does Mechanize onerror callback set content to error message?

Tags: perl, callback, www-mechanize

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize( onerror => \&mecherror );
$mech->get("http://stackoverflow.comxxxx");
print $mech->content;
sub mecherror {
    $mech->get("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

The output on line 4 is an error string relating to the first failed get and not the content of the get executed in `sub mecherror`.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

The `onerror` callback of [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) is meant to supply a response to error

> - onerror => \&func
>     Reference to a die-compatible function, such as Carp::croak, that is called when there's a fatal error.

It is clearly not intended for recovery or any use of the object that is being constructed.

That said, your call in `onerror` works, but the object doesn't get to know about it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize( onerror => \&mecherror );
$mech->get("http://stackoverflow.comxxxx");
say $mech->content;

sub mecherror {
    my $response = $mech->get("http://stackoverflow.com");
    # say $mech->content;
    say "response is " . ref($response);
    say $response->decoded_content;
}
```

This shows that we duly got an [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) object, and prints out the page. Then we may hope to pass a reference to the callback to connect it to the calling code. However, a mechanism for this is not provided -- this is not supported. We *are* warned against messing with internals, though.

As for why the object isn't updated, it depends on the callback implementation. From the [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) we see that the code reference goes into object's data and is run when needed via the wrapper

```
sub die {
    my $self = shift;
    return unless my $handler = $self->{onerror};
    return $handler->(@_);
}
```

A lot of other code is involved when this triggers, while nothing is done here to change the object's state. That is just unsupported and may result in undefined behavior.

Note that the callback here knows what `$mech` is because it is global, so it has the right object.

---

To summarize discussions in comments, it is plausible that the page retrieved by the callback gets overwritten by the error message. We get to see this when invoking `content`, and it appears to be due to this part of the method (see source)

```
$content = $self->response()->decoded_content(charset => 'none');
```

The `decoded_content` method is from `HTTP::Response`, inherited via [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), and the error message indeed seems to have come from that class. (Neither W::M nor LWP::UA have a method named "decode_content.") This is summarized in [W::M::content](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Econtent%28...%29) page

> `$mech->content(...)`
>   Returns the content that the mech uses internally for the last page fetched. Ordinarily this is the same as `$mech->response()->decoded_content()`,  [ ... ]

However, we anyway couldn't rely on the object being in a consistent state, as discussed.

Comment: But the callback is executed well after the object has finished being constructed, so it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @CJ7 This is about the call inside `onerror`, where the page is retrieved successfully.  I don't know when that gets executed -- how it is implemented.  Except that `$mech` doesn't get that content. I just tried -- remove the bad call and just print content right after the `new`. It is uninitialized.

Comment: If you remove the bad call then `onerror` definitely won't be called so what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @CJ7  You are right.  I was referring to some other things I tried, sorry for the imprecise comment.  I've updated the answer to what I think is likely to be going on.  In short, it's just unsupported.  The class would have to go out of its way so that the callback code, executed during another call, can change the state of the object.  But since this is not the intent of it, it doesn't do anything toward that end.

Comment: Yes, I think that must be what is happening.  The callback seems to be referencing a different `$mech` or not being able to change its state as you say.  It would be good to be able to check the memory address of the object reference to see if it is the same, but I can't find a function to do that.

Comment: @CJ7 Right, another thing I should've stated -- the callback knows what `$mech` is just because it's global. So I think that it is the same object so the code in the callback works, but the state of the object cannot be changed during that call.

Comment: I have noticed that `$mech->uri` will be updated correctly after returning from the callback.  It's just not updating `content` correctly.

Comment: @CJ7 That's interesting -- that would be the "undefined behavior."  Some things may work some may not.

Comment: I think maybe the `Mechanize` code is changing `content` at the end of the callback, but when I looked at the source I couldn't see it doing this.

Comment: @CJ7 Yes, that may well be the case, that it overwrites it. I'll look at code tomorrow, I am curious.

Comment: @CJ7 I looked through the code, I agree that it is likely that the content gets overwritten with the error.  But I think it's pulled from one of the classes W::M inherits from (the error printed seems to be coming from ... `HTTP::Response` perhaps?)  But the bottom line is that it's just not supported -- even if the error weren't overwriting the content we couldn't be sure that the object's state is OK, since it does nothing in the callback to ensure that.  (In normal operation all kinds of methods are involved for it.)  I updated my post so to sumarrize some of this.

Comment: @zdim LWP::UserAgent (which WWW::Mechanize inherits from) returns errors as HTTP::Response objects, probably so you don't have to add special handling for HTTP errors vs. other types of errors. See https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-get-url

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Ah, thank you! I know that `get` is from LWP and that we get `HTTP::Response`.  But since  `W::M::content` checks a bunch of parameters (which are hard to trace) I wasn't sure where the error is from.  It looks like it'd have to be in `response()->decoded_content` part, which is `HTTP::Response`. I think that bulk of W::M is LWP, but it sometimes pulls in other things directly.  Thank you.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot `$mech->content` is being set to an error string. It has nothing to do with `HTTP::Response`.

Comment: @CJ7 `$mech->content` calls `$mech->response()->content()` or `$mech->response()->decoded_content()` [behind the scenes](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/WWW-Mechanize-1.80/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#L244), where `$mech->response()` returns an HTTP::Response object; so yes, it has everything to do with HTTP::Response. This is a feature of LWP::UserAgent.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OK, I see that `$mech->response->decoded_content` does contain the content, but `$mech->content` only has the error string.  Why?

Comment: @CJ7 The `$mech->content` uses `$mech->response->decoded_content` from `HTTP::Response`, inherited from `LWP::UserAgent` (W::M doesn't have a method with that name, nor does LWP::UA).  This displays the error string written previously, at some point during the bad call, which overwrote the page initially written by `get` in the callback, like you said.  Note that almost all work done in `W::M` is really from other classes, like `LWP::UserAgent` (and a number of others).  The error message itself bears clear trademark of `HTTP::Response`.  I added some of this to the end of the answer.

Comment: @CJ7  At what exact point the overwriting happened is nigh impossible to say since the trail of calls and arguments passed around in W::M's code gets more and more complex.